# How to close window from button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this window:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function()
 {  
      jQuery("#loginWindow").kendoWindow({
          "modal":true,
          "iframe":false,
          "draggable":true,
         "pinned":false,
         "title":"Login",
         "resizable":false,
         "content":null,
        "width":300,
        "height":350,
        "actions":["Close"]
    });
});
</script>
```

It has a close button in the top right, but I also want to put a button on the bottom of the form it is on to close it.

Here is the form.  Instead of closing the form, it makes the ajax call just like the submit button.

```
     <form action="/Account/Login" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#loginSection" method="post">    
        <div id="loginSection"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            <button onclick="cancelLogin()" >Cancel</button>
            <script>
                function cancelLogin()
                {
                    var window = $("#registerWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                    window.close();
                } 
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues with the above:

1. The name of the window was wrong.
2. I needed to set the button type="button"

Then it worked.

Greg